# Unknown resource file entry starting with >>

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In a Visual Studio resource file (.resx) for a C# project I've located strange entries which start with two greater-than signs (`>>`), e.g.:

```xml
<data name="&gt;&gt;$this.Type" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Framework.Forms.MyForm, Framework, Version=1.1.5127.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f4aaf1fba1062dc8</value>
</data>
```

These entries sort of reference various classes (`MyForm`, `MyButton`, etc.) in a custom framework library but in an outdated version.

Are these entries still valid? Should I change them so that they reference the current framework version? Do they have an impact on the project? Why does the name start with `>>`?

Answer (score 1):

This is how .Net/Winforms stores text resources from Windows forms classes, if you have set "Localizable" to "True". This way, they are taken out of the .designer.cs code and are put into a resource file (one for every language supported) that can be switched, depending on the chosen language.
This is at least the one case I know, where resources appear that start with ">>".

Comment: Ok, that at least explains for me that `>>` in the name is valid in this context. But I still don't know why outdated versions are referenced. I've seen entries with the correct version, though.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am faced with the same issue.  I updated my assembly version and I want to know how to autogenerate the new version in there resource files.  It seems to work with the old one, but still not comfortable leaving it like that.

Comment: @AndySousa not, not really. I suspected they're the cause of compile errors but that was not true. In one of the projects there are still many references to the old framework version in those RESX files but so far I've not noticed any problems with that.